# How can I move my nixops source files?

Tags: nixos

I kept my nixops source files in one directory, but then I decided to move them to another directory.

How can I tell nixops that the source files have changed? Can I just change the nixEprs row in DeploymentAttrs in `~/.nixops/deployment.nixops`?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the machine definitions you want to move then just move the files and run `nixops modify new-locations.nix -d name`.

As long as the name is the same then the deploy is kept the same too.